# Reg exp. with optional parameters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm in need of reg-exp to match some text and then resulting in a CTA-button. What I want is, that the following text will result in the output:

### EXAMPLE 1

```
{BUTTON text="(some text)" link="(some link)" target="(target, OPTIONAL)" class="(classes, OPTIONAL)"}

<a href="(some link)" target="(target)" class="$4">(some text)</a>
```

### EXAMPLE 2

```
{BUTTON text="(some text)" link="(some link)" target="(target, OPTIONAL)"}

<a href="(some link)" target="(target)">(some text)</a>
```

### EXAMPLE 3

```
{BUTTON text="(some text)" link="(some link)"}

<a href="(some link)">(some text)</a>
```

My own "solution" is this, but I don't think it's the "correct" way to do it - in other words i'm quite certain, it has flaws!

```
{BUTTON text="([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)" link="([A-Za-z0-9\/\:\.\?\=]+)"( target=")?([a-zA-Z\_]+)?(")? ( class=")?([a-zA-Z\_]+)?(")?}
```

Comment: It's good that you provided your attempt, but I think it would be clearer and you'd have a better chance at getting a response if you provides examples of expected input and output. It's not clear from your description above what text is literal and what text is variable.

Comment: Peter: I have now provided some examples - I hope that's enough :)

Comment: I assume the `$4` is a mistake in the first example, but that aside:
* Is there really the string `, OPTIONAL` at the end of the `target` and `class` properties?
* Are you guaranteed not to have `"` characters in the middle of double-quoted strings?
* Do you need to check for the existence of the all the parentheses shown in your examples?

Comment: Peter: What I need is for my users in my backend to make a link with a href and a title... And then I need them to have the possibility to provide a target and class for the link - but I don't want to DEMAND they do. Makes sense? :)

Comment: I'm going to leave you in the capable hands of @Barmar :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use non-capturing groups for the parts that aren't in the replacement (or change the numbers in the replacement to account for all of them):

```
{BUTTON text="([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)" link="([A-Za-z0-9\/\:\.\?\=]+)"\s*(target="[a-zA-Z\_]+")?\s*(class="[a-zA-Z\_]+")?}
```

The replacement string should then be:

```
<a href="$2" $3 $4>$1</a>
```

Notice that I made the whole `target="..."` and `class="..."` elements into a single optional group, so that they can be subsituted in their entirety into the replacement.

Here's how you can do it to just capture the class name, and merge it in with other classes in the template:

```
{BUTTON text="([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)" link="([A-Za-z0-9\/\:\.\?\=]+)"\s*(target="[a-zA-Z\_]+")?\s*(?:class="([a-zA-Z\_]+)")?}

<a href="$2" $3 class="c1 c2 $4">$1</a>
```

This uses a non-capturing group to match the whole `class="..."` element, and then only captures the `...` part.

Comment: What if i need to have some extra classes added, that doesn't need to be in the {BUTTON}-tag, but has to be in the HTML-output? :)

Comment: I get this error: Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 85     on line 50

Comment: I accidentally left out the parenthesis before `target`. Fixed.